# How can i declare an environment variable which would stay in a docker container?

Tags: shell, maven, gitlab, devops, environment

I'm trying using

```
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/ant/apache-ant-1.10.11/bin:/maven/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin
```

and calling it on a script as

```
export PATH=$PATH:/ant/apache-ant-1.10.11/bin:/maven/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin
```

And it just won't work. It seems that the variables are erased after the pipeline for building the image. It just works if i send it maunally from the container itself, but i need it to stay and be like that because it is for devOps and it will use that variable for compiling (i have the 2 techonologies just for testing)

```
Any hints? I'm in a hurry.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `env` keyword inside your docker file, like follow:

```
ENV PATH=$PATH:/ant/apache-ant-1.10.11/bin:/maven/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin
```

Here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env more information.